# How to compare data between two different columns in two different databases with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I am new to SQL server and I have two databases with two different tables, they are on the same server and I am using Microsoft SQL Server management studio.
I need to compare two columns and find which entries do not show up in both columns. Some of these results do match up and I only want to find the differences.

Databases and fields that need querying:

database1, ID number 
database2, complex ID number

I would just like to find out the entries that do not match up between the two using SQL.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What table's in those databases have the fields(columns)?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure to reference each piece with the 3 or 4 part name.

Database.Schema.Table when referencing tables
and
Database.Schema.Table.Column when referencing columns

You can write joins between databases this way and definitely pull data from more than one database.

Answer (score 0):

use linked server
[see this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx)

read all, at the end you have the use of sql statements use

Comment: You don't need linked servers for databases on the same server.